# Can't see steps in profile workflow when debugging through plugin registration tool

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to `debug workflow using plugin registration tool` for dynamics crm so I install Plugin profiler in pluginregistration tool and click on profile workflow and select my workflow in step 1 but can't see anything in step. what should I do for steps?

[image]

Please suggest me any solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

Your CRM version (8 vs 9) has to match the Plugin Registration Tool version (8 vs 9) that is found in the SDK. So if your CRM online version is 8.2, then you MUST use the Plugin Registration Tool found in the CRM SDK for version 8.2.

Other possible reason could be if you didn't try using the on demand process you created with the custom workflow activity in it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the plugin registration tool cannot be used to debug workflow activities. It is intended to debug plugin code in CRM Online. This is because in CRM Online you cannot attach the debugger to the executing process.

When you can work On Premise you should be able to attach the debugger to the Dynamics CRM Asynchronous service. An alternative (i.m.o. recommended) approach is to build a private VM and do most of your development there.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the workflow you want to debug, calls the custom workflow only once(1 step) alone. Debug your workflow and then modify your system workflow.

Comment: In my case, CRM version was 9.* and I was using older Plugin Registration Tool Version 8.2.*. With Plugin Registration Tool Version 9.*, it Worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and stumbled on this post. I found by playing around with my workflow that I had to make the workflow that triggers the action a synchronous one to make it work (excuse the French interface):

[image: Convert to Synchronous Workflow]

And miracle, the steps appeared in the workflow :

[image: Workflow Steps]